# reading lines from file into lists for a specific field

Tags: python, file

I have the following text file `job.txt`. I want to `extract` few fields like `48638` (without the words cluster),the time field ,`Q` in every line into a list.

Please do guide me, I have tried these :

```
content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
stlist=content[2:]
```

to delete the first two lines but not able to get the output as below.

Output of the list must be like :

```
48758 45:00:40 R qp32
```

`job.txt-is` as follows :

```
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - -----
48638.tyrone-cluster             ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss                 0 Q qp32           
48738.tyrone-cluster             case3sqTS1e-4    mecvamsi        588:30:5 R qp32          
48758.tyrone-cluster             meshA5           mecmdjim        45:00:40 R qp32
```

EDIT:The above file can also be in other format like this 
the text of the file without spaces is as below.the original file consists of spaces like the above code.

```
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
------------------------- ---------------- --------------- -------- - ----
48998.tyrone-cluster          gic1_nwgs                  mbupi           18:45:44           R             qp32           
48999.tyrone-cluster           gic2_nwgs           mbupi                  0 Q batch          
49005.tyrone-cluster        ...01R-1849-01_2 mcbkss          00:44:23 R qp32           
8687.tyrone-cluster        gaussian_top.sh  chemraja               0 Q qp32           
49047.tyrone-cluster        jet_egrid        asevelt         312:33:0 R qp128          
49052.tyrone-cluster        case3sqTS1e-4    mecvamsi               0 Q qp32           
49053.tyrone-cluster         ...01R-1850-01_1 mcbkss                 0 Q batch          
49054.tyrone-cluster        ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss                 0 Q batch
```

So each time the format changes can anyone help me in getting a generalized function to handle all these different types in the file.

Comment: what did you try this far?

Comment: please edit your question and add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the lines with a regular expression.
The fields you want to display, you can place them in capture groups by surrounding the relevant parts of the regular expression with parentheses.
You can pull out those capture groups using the group() method on your regex match result.

```
import re

# joblist list will store each line of parsed output
joblist=[]
prog = re.compile('^(\d+)\..*\s+.*\s+\w+\s+(.*)\s+(\w)\s+(.*)$')
with open('job.txt','r') as jobfile:
        for line in jobfile.readlines():
                result = prog.match(line)
        # Handle header line and skip lines that don't match regex
                if result is None:
                    continue
                else:
                    joblist.append(' '.join([result.group(1), result.group(2), result.group(3), result.group(4)]))

# displaying the list
for job in joblist:
    print job
```

The data you provided:

```
macbook:Downloads joeyoung$ cat job.txt
Job id                    Name             User            Time Use S Queue
48638.cluster ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss 0 Q qp32
48738.cluster case3sqTS1e-4 mecvamsi 588:30:5 R qp32
48758.cluster meshA5 mecmdjim 45:00:40 R qp32
48638.tyrone-cluster ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss 0 Q qp32
48708.tyrone-cluster ...onwgs_entries mbupi 0 Q qp32
48736.tyrone-cluster ...01R-1850-01_1 mcbkss 0 Q batch
48737.tyrone-cluster ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss 0 Q batch
```

The output of the script on the above data (including the newly request time field in column 2):

```
macbook:Downloads joeyoung$ python parsejob.py
48638 0 Q qp32
48738 588:30:5 R qp32
48758 45:00:40 R qp32
48638 0 Q qp32
48708 0 Q qp32
48736 0 Q batch
48737 0 Q batch
```

The parsed data is available in the **joblist** list variable.

Comment: hi, i am getting an error in the above code as 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' could you please help me out

Comment: @sharath The original data you provided at the time I submitted my answer did not include a header line.  The header line does not match the regular expression and causes there to be no data to display in the capture groups of the results of the regex evaluation.  I edited my answer to ignore the header line and any lines that don't match the regex.

Comment: yeah i tried it without the header files but again got the error also i am using the same code that you have given error: print ' '.join([result.group(1),result.group(2),result.group(3)])
IndexError: no such group

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: the file job.txtx is as follows                                                    48638.tyrone-cluster       ...01R-1850-01_2 mcbkss                 0 Q qp32           
48708.tyrone-cluster       ...onwgs_entries mbupi                  0 Q qp32           
48736.tyrone-cluster       ...01R-1850-01_1 mcbkss                 0 Q batch          
48738.tyrone-cluster       case3sqTS1e-4    mecvamsi        588:30:5 R qp32

Comment: I modified the regex to work with your new data as well as the original data.  I changed the word check "\w+" followed by whitespace "\s+"to search for any characters ".*" followed by whitespace "\s+"

Comment: thank you the above code runs fine but only prints the last line and also can i get the 588:30:5 or 0  (48738.cluster       case3sqTS1e-4    mecvamsi        588:30:5 R qp32) in each line with the output and also i have to assign it to a list .

Comment: @sharath Answer has been updated with time field in column 2 and also provided a joblist variable where you can get the parsed lines in a list.  Also updated the answer with the output from my terminal to show its correctness for the provided data.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a bit overkill here, you can use string splitting instead and use `islice` to ignore the first two lines. Take everything up to the first `.` from those, then the last two words from the remainder, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('job.txt') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 2, None):
        num, _, rest = line.partition('.')
        _, letter, code = rest.rsplit(None, 2)
        print num, letter, code
```

Comment: i am getting an error: num, _, rest = s.partition('.')
NameError: name 's' is not defined
 is there any import statement missing

Comment: @sharath nope sorry - typo - should be `line` not `s` :) (updated)